# HTML Input type Button: not valid attribute

Tags: asp.net, button, webforms

in an old ASP.NET Web Forms application I got this warning in the aspx code of a page:

Attribute 'fullname' is not a valid attribute for element 'input'

Why was written in this way?

And there is a way to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You only get a warning. The simple issue is that the developer just made up a attribute, and shoved in some value. this is legal, and I often do this for say a standard text box.

so, I might for example place 5 or 10 text boxes and controls inside of a div, say like this:

```
<div id="EditRecord" runat="server" style="float:left;display: normal;border:solid 2px;padding:5px">
  <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
    <label>HotelName</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" f="HOtelName" width="280" />  <br />
    <label>First Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140" /> <br />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140" /> <br />
    <label>City</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" f="City" Width="140" /> <br />
    <label>Province</label><asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" f="Province" Width="75"></asp:TextBox> <br />
  </div>
  etc. etc. etc.
```

Note in above, I wanted to define what data base column for a routine to "fill out" the above controls.

So, I have a routine I call with a data row.

```
        Call fLoader(EditRecord, rstData.Rows(0))
```

the above routine looks for any control with a "f=datacolum", and fills out the controls for me.

So, I get this:

[image]

In other words, my custom "f" attribute allows me to pull data from a database, and fill out the web page - and without having to write new code each time. (and I have a reverse routine - writes out all controls with f="some data column" back to the database. With this simple concept, then I am able to have any web page read/write data to/from the database - and not have to write that same code over and over. In effect, I get a whole crud system, and all achieved by a simple concept of adding a "made up" attribute "f" that defines the data base column to use.

So, you can in VS have that warning suppressed, but I as noted OFTEN make and add some custom values. Even for a button in a grid view, you might have this:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="Button"     
             OnClick="cmdView_Click"
             ProductID = '<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
             CustomerID = '<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>'                 
             />
```

And then in code behind, you have this:

```
Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender

    Debug.Print(btn.Attributes("CustomerID").ToString())
    Debug.Print(btn.Attributes("ProductID").ToString())
```

So, we often just make up some attribute, and it is legal to do so in most cases.

So, that button - say dropped into a grid view now can pass values to the button click - even values not displayed in the gridview.

So, you can just as a general rule ignore the warning. It is not super common, but a lot of developers often will add and make up their own attributes, and client side code (JavaScript) or even code behind as above shows is then free to use the values in those custom, or "made up" attributes. In most cases, you get a warning, but other then that, it not a huge deal nor issue. You of course do have to be carful, since such custom attributes in most cases don't have automatic view state, and their values will not persist correctly for a round trip (post-back, and page return). However, for expressions or values such as above example, then its not a problem.